# Force Safari for Mac to print with no padding/margins as well as remember the paper size

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, printing, safari, zebra-printers

i have spent q good bit of time getting a zebra printer to work with os x for barcode printing from a browser.

the difficulty i am now having is with safari properly displaying the margins/padding. even though i have all margins etc. set to 0 with CSS with @page and body, html. it still prints with about 1/4" margin. does anyone know a way to remove this? it works fine in chrome and firefox scales it so small it's unreadable when using 4x1" paper settings.

as an aside, is it possible to for Safari (or any app) to remember the paper size from the last print job? even when i save the print profile, it always defaults to Default paper size.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried generating a PDF instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like safari automatically adds the 1/4" border as not all printers are capable of edge-to-edge output. For optimum output quality and overall control you need to write native ZPL code and spool to the device.